# VSCode Python: Shifting code to a new line keeps all the white spaces of previous indentation

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, formatting

If I take this snippet of code:

```
def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
    print("Context menu event!")
```

And then I pull the "print" line up inline with the "def" line, then hit enter to return the "print" line back below I get this:

```
def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
            print("Context menu event!")
```

Notice how it keeps the white space from the previous indentation and then adds more white space for a new indentation?  In other editors, the old white space indentation gets removed and the line gets indented properly.  So I am trying to figure out how to get VSCode to do this as well.  Is this a bug or a setting?

EDIT:

For clarification on what I am doing....if you put the cursor to the right of the : and hit delete it should bring the bottom line up to the cursor line.  Then if you hit enter immediately in VSCode you will get what I described above.  In other editors it will format the new line properly by remove the extra indentation.

I use this a lot to clean up some code, especially example code that I'm pasting into my own code.

Comment: which if line you talk about?

Comment: @ Cyber-Tech oh crap, sorry that was a mistype.  I'll change it.

Comment: do you mean when you set the cursor close to print and click on backspace, the entire print line goes forward instead of backward?

Comment: @Cyber-Tech  See my edit above for clarification.

Comment: @Berkyjay Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: @JillCheng It's better than nothing.  I'll look closer into the Formatting settings as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default setting of VSCode, currently we cannot change it through custom settings, but according to your description, it is recommended that you could try to set VSCode in the following ways to automatically standardize the code format.

1. You could add the following settings to the `settings.json` file in the `.vscode` folder. After setting, when we save the file, it will automatically standardize the indentation of the code.

> `"editor.formatOnSave": true,`

Before:

[image]

Ctrl+S

After：

[image]

2. In addition, you could also automatically standardize the code format by setting Formatting of VSCode. Reference: [Formatting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_formatting).

Answer (score 0):

The indentation is added before where the cursor is placed. If I put cursor right in front of `print` like this:

```py
def contextMenuEvent(self, event):    |print("Context menu event!")
```

Then hit enter, this is what I got:

```py
def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
    print("Context menu event!")
```